# How to pull data from sub-array, and combine

Tags: php, mysql

I do a database call to list all the "categories" that belong to a user. This returns to me an array, with sub-arrays with specific data on each category.

How do I pick out the category IDs from these, and combine them to form a new query that grabs all the posts in these categories?

---

Tables: "assignments" and "classes".

Assigments: assignmentid, classid, ...
Classes: classname, userid, ...

Here's the code I'm using.

```
$query = dbquery("SELECT classid, classinfo FROM classes WHERE userid = 1");
```

This returns to me an array with subarrays:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [classid] => 2 [classinfo] => classinfo )
[1] => Array ( [classid] => 3 [classinfo] => classinfo ) 
...
```

How would I extract out all the classids, and then list them as "2 OR 3 OR ..." for use in another MySQL query?

Comment: Is this homework? If so please add the homework tag.

Comment: This is not homework. This is for a startup :)

Comment: @Brandodn: add in the description, the tables you have and their fields or the tables' definitions code. At least for the `classes` and `posts` tables.

Comment: OK. SO, it's not `posts` but `assignments`. Anyway, I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to do that (get the classids in PHP and then send another query). You could simply use the query you have with something like:

```
SELECT assignments.assignmentid      
     , assignments.classid
     , assignments.otherfield
FROM assignments
WHERE assignments.classid IN 
  ( SELECT classid, classinfo
    FROM classes
    WHERE userid = 1
  )
```

or

```
SELECT assignments.assignmentid      --- or whatever fields you want
     , assignments.classid           --- from table assignments
     , classes.classinfo           --- or table classes
FROM assignments
  JOIN classes
    ON assignments.classid = classes.classid
WHERE classes.userid = 1
```

Both these queries will show almost same results (if you remove the `classes.classinfo` from the second query, the results will be identical). That is, all assignments data that are related to a class with userid = 1.

---

There are numerous SQL tutorials on the web. You can try for example: **[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)**

Comment: Whoa, I did not know you could do that!

Comment: Second way is usually faster in MYSQL, with propper indexes (at least in the fields that are used in JOIN and WHERE).

Comment: I'm not particularly clear on how to use your second way; could you elaborate a bit more? I included my table names and their fields in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: So when I go and foreach() your second example, when I ask for $query['classinfo'] I will only get the class information related to that assignment?

Comment: I just nearly peed my pants... that's amazing.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` over the array of categories, building a new array or simple string that you can include in a post query.

That's about all I can say, without having some specific code to critique. Though, sounds like something you could do completely in SQL. (May or may not be applicable depending on your caching needs.)